# How top create model for arrays of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, model

Im trying to set the api return to one variable, works, but throw errors in console, why is this happening? and how to solve it?

my ts:

```js
public myData = new myDataModel();


getData(){
    this.myCoolService.getDataAPI()
      .subscribe((res) => {
     this.myData = res['dataBean'][0];
});
}
```

my api retunrs this:

```
{ 
   "code":0,
   "financialInformationBean":[ 
      { 
         "name":{ 
            "value":"abc"
         },
         "color":{ 
            "value":"green"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and my model is:

```js
export class myDataModel {
  name: Value;
  color: Value;
}

export interface Value {
  value: string;
}
```

and my html:

```html
<span>{{ myData.name.value }}</span>
```

my console output this: `WalletComponent.html:30 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

i already tried this in my html, my console dont showed any erros but i got this in `[Object] [Object]` in my page:

```html
<span>{{ myData.name}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use TypeScript's [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) rather than classes. I am not sure why you are using both classes and interfaces for defining the typings, since you seem to have an idea of how interfaces work.

This is how you can construct the interface for `myData`.

```
export interface myDataModel {
  name: Value;
  color: Value;
}

export interface Value {
  value: string;
}
```

And on your component.ts,

```
myData: myDataModel;

getData(){
  this.myCoolService.getDataAPI().subscribe((res) => {
     this.myData = res['dataBean'][0];
  });
}
```

In addition, on your component.html, you will need to use the elvis operator, also known as the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). This is because HTTP requests are asynchronous, thus the value of `myData` will be undefined when the component is initially rendered. Therefore, the following operator will prevent the view from being rendered without any errors.

```
<span>{{ myData?.name.value }}</span>
```